# Getting errors while casting into Date fields : org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar

Tags: java, sql, db2, jdbctemplate

How do I need to send the value of the field so that it is casted properly. Currently, I am sending Date type field with **value -> 2020-10-10**
Here is the query :

```
                 query.append("SELECT * from STUDENT where")
                .append(" CAST(STUDENT.ADM_DTTM AS DATE) BETWEEN")
                .append(" CAST(")
                .append("?")
                .append(" AS DATE) AND")
                .append(" CURRENT_DATE-5 DAY");

             final Date[] args = new Date[]{getMyDate()};
             int[] types = new int[]{Types.DATE};
             result = jdbcTemplate.query(query, args, types, new Mapper());
```

Here is the detailed stacktrace :

```
nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-313, SQLSTATE=07001, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.19.66
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:101) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1444) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:632) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:669) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:700) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:706) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
```

Edit 1: Added the parameters passed to match the number of parameters markers in the query

```
 final Date[] args = new Date[]{
            getMyDate(),
            getMyDate(),
            getMyDate(),
            getMyDate()
    };
    int[] types = new int[]{Types.DATE, Types.DATE, Types.DATE, Types.DATE};
```

Error :

```
nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-401, SQLSTATE=42818, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.19.66
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:93) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1444) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:632) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:669) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:700) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:706) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
```

Comment: The SQLCODE=-313 is quite specific. Lookup SQL0313N in the docs.  It means that too many, or too few values were supplied for the statement for binding. This is normally a programming mistake.

Comment: Thanks @mao, I am having this where clause at 4 places in my query, do I need to pass it 4 times, how should I pass exactly, please help.

Comment: The number of parameters supplied to run the query must exactly match the number of parameter-markers in the query . Even if it is the same date value each time.

Comment: Thanks @mao, I updated the code , but I am still getting errors. Please have a look

Comment: If you change the question (with new symptom), then it is a moving target.  New symptom => new question.   Please learn how to lookup error messages (negative SQLCODE values) in the Db2 Knowledge centre free online, and act on the documented recommendations there . Your original symptom is now solved by matching the __number__ of parameters with the number of parameter-markers.  Next you must match the datatypes also.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you shouldn't need any casting at all in your DB2 query:

```
SELECT *
FROM STUDENT
WHERE ADM_DTTM >= ? AND ADM_DTTM < CURRENT_DATE - 5 DAY;
```

The reasons for this is that first the lower bound of your range comparison is a valid DB2 date literal.  This should not require any casting to represent the date.  Second, since `ADM_DTTM` is a datetime (presumably) we don't need to cast it.  If it would pass as a datetime, it would also still pass when cast to a date.

I omitted the actual updated code for your JDBC template query.  Assuming the syntax there is already correct, the above query should not be giving you any errors.